# Small external hard drive in time machine

Tags: time-machine

I have a external hard dive that is smaller than the hard drive of the computer. Can I use that external hard drive as time machine but select just the most important information to be back up and perhaps a second hard drive for the rest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, in System Preferences > Time Machine, select the small drive, click the options button and exclude anything you don't want to back up.